# Anyone can recommend combinatorics book that has solution manual?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn about combinatorics,but the most problem I can't set up math model that suitable for the problem.That is why I want solution manual.
please recommend some textbook for me

Comment: [*Combinatorial Problems and Exercises*](https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Problems-Exercises-Chelsea-Publishing/dp/0821842625) by [László Lovász](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1szl%C3%B3_Lov%C3%A1sz).

Comment: Schaum's Outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bender and Williamson](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gill/FoundCombSite/Resources/ySOLUTION.pdf), Applied Combinatorics.
[Grimaldi](http://www.slideshare.net/henrypeter2/discrete-and-combinatorial-mathematics-solutions-manual-grimaldi), Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics.
[DeTemple and Webb](http://au.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118830784,subjectCd-MA90.html), Combinatorial Reasoning.
[Tucker](https://www.scribd.com/doc/86627670/Applied-Combinatorics-5th-Edition-by-Tucker-Instructor-s-Manual), Applied Combinatorics.
Or just type *combinatorics solutions manual* into the internet, and see what comes back at you.